# laravel testbench error 500 while testing

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-testing

while testing a laravel package with [Orchestral/testbench](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench), I'm getting error 500. but the exception handling do not say much why the error happend.

here is the `TestCase.php`

```php
<?php

namespace DivineAlien\Gourl\Tests;

use DivineAlien\Gourl\GourlServiceProvider;
use Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase as Orchestra;

abstract class TestCase extends Orchestra
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    protected function getPackageProviders($app)
    {
        return [
            GourlServiceProvider::class,
        ];
    }

    protected function getEnvironmentSetUp($app)
    {
        $app['config']->set('app.env', 'testing');
        $app['config']->set('app.debug', true);

        $app['config']->set('database.connections.testing', [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_TEST_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_TEST_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_TEST_USERNAME', 'laravel'),
            'password' => env('DB_TEST_PASSWORD', 'laravel'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
        ]);

        $app['config']->set('logging.default', 'single');
        $app['config']->set('logging.channels.single', [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'tap' => [App\Logging\CustomizeFormatter::class],
            'path' => __DIR__.'/logs/test.log',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ]);
    }
}
```

[image]

I wan't the full error message not just a exception saying hey you have an error!

Comment: You can do `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` in your test case to allow the exception to be handled by the test so you can see what is wrong.

Comment: still the same message.

Comment: The logs might have the error in as well.

Comment: there is no log file! i wanted to ask another question about the app not saving any log too..

Comment: @alien `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` will always show you the real exception, are you writing it as the first line of your failing test ? Can you share the final test with it written ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti i was wrong. i didn't put the `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` on the first line so it didn't worked. after put it on the first line of the function, it worked properly.

Comment: @alien Awesome, I am assuming you fix your problem, did you ? We can help you if you did not.

Comment: yes the problem fixed thank you.